# Minimizing Individual Assets with Webpack

Tags: wordpress, optimization, webpack

I would like to optimize a wordpress website with webpack. The application is not a single page app, and each page requires their own styles, scripts, and images in the head. I would like to use webpack to minimize css, js, and images in place. I don't need a single bundle file.

In a folder with three css files, I would like to iterate through each of the files and minimize them.

```
css/
page.css ---> page.css(minimized)
header.css ---> header.css(minimized)
footer.css ---> footer.css(minimized)
```

I would like to do the same with js files and use an image optimizer for jpgs, png, ect. Can this be done with webpack? If so, how could this be done? I have read about multiple entry points but that does not seem to be what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, multiple entry points will still only give one output. What you could do, is write a wrapping script which wraps your `webpack.config.js` and having the entry config variable set to be dynamic.

Pseudo-code:

```
import glob from 'glob' 
import webpack from 'webpack' 
import config from './webpack.config'

const files = glob.glob('**/my-entry-file.js');

files.forEach((file) => {
    config.entry = file;
    webpack(config);
});
```